# How can i Hide and Show Submit button when one is button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am retrieving some data from database and show them in a html table.but right now i am struggling with the following scenario.

if user clicks disable button it should be hide and enable button should be show.if user clicks on enable button it should be hide and disable button should be show.

Here is my code

```
<html>
<title></title>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('input:submit').click(function(){
            $('input:submit').attr("disabled", true);
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<?php

echo "<table border='1' align='center' width='100%'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Image</th>
<th>Modified Date</th>
<th>URL</th>
<th>Clicks</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $id = $row['img_id'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['img_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' width='500px'>" . '<img width = 200px; height=100px; src=" '. ($row['img_path']) . '"/>'. "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' width='350px'>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['url'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['clicks'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'><a href='image_update.php?id=$id'><button>Update</button></a>

    <form method='post' >

        <input type='hidden' name='tid' value='$id'/>
        <input type='submit' name='disable' id='disable' value='Disable'>
         <input type='submit' name='enable' id='enable' value='Enable'>
    </form>

    </td>";

    $id = $_POST['tid'];
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {


        $sql = "UPDATE advertisementnew SET status = 'Disabled' WHERE img_id='$id'";
        mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    }

    echo "</tr>";

}


echo "</table>";
```

Comment: where is javascript or jquery in OP?

Comment: On click of each button toggle both buttons display property. Initially show one button and hide another one. 
You can also do this by adding classes to buttons and using toggleClass on click

Comment: This has nothing to do with php. You should post the html output which inclues your javascript.

Comment: Using $('button').hide() will work too

Answer (score 0):

try this js:

```
$('#enable').css("display", "none");
    $('#disable').click(function(){
            $('#enable').css("display", "block");
             $('#disable').css("display", "none");
    });
```

instead of:

```
$('input:submit').click(function(){
            $('input:submit').attr("disabled", true);
        });
```

Comment: try this:
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#enable').css("display", "none");
    $('#disable').click(function(){
            $('#enable').css("display", "block");
             $('#disable').css("display", "none");
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

can you try this hope this is works

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    $('input:submit').click(function () {
    var check = $(this).attr('id');
    if (check == 'disable') {
        $('#enable').show();
        $('#disable').hide();
    }
    if (check == 'enable') {
        $('#disable').show();
        $('#enable').hide();
    }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: you include two time your jquery min js. please remove one js. in header section.

Comment: check if your firebug is on then what error you return in console ?

Comment: try this js code after the body finish don't write on the head. put it where body tag finish and before html tag finish.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhh That not works because when hit the submit button so page reload and script not works.

Answer (score 0):

You can have class

```
.hide-show{
   display : none;
}
```

HTML :

```
<input type='submit' name='disable' id='disable' value='Disable' class="enable-disable-btn">
<input type='submit' name='enable' id='enable' value='Enable' class="enable-disable-btn hide-show">
```

Initially put the `hide-show` class on the button which  should be need to hide.
Add class `enable-disable-btn` to both button enabled/disbaled
JS:

You can use [jQuery#toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```
$(".enable-disable-btn").on('click',function(){

     $(".enable-disable-btn").toggleClass('hide-show')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to add unique id dynamically created in while loop in your case id is not unique

 for this

changes in php replace these two lines


<input type='submit'  onclick='doEnableDesable(this)' name='disable' id='disable".$id."' value='Disable'>
<input type='submit' onclick='doEnableDesable(this)' name='enable' id='enable".$id."' value='Enable'>


And in javascript define function for dynamic Id


function doEnableDesable(params)
{
 if (params.value == 'disable') {
        $('#'+params.id).show();
        $('#'+params.id).hide();
    }
    if (params.value == 'enable') {
        $('#'+params.id).show();
        $('#'+params.id).hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: and then check function call or not ?

Comment: function is not called

Comment: please replace 
remove = by mistake it added and then check



function doEnableDesable(params)